# Solving a recursive integral

Tags: integration

I'm trying to compute the following integral:
$$
\lambda m(x) =\frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \int_{\max(\alpha x - \varepsilon, -1)} ^{\min(\alpha x + \varepsilon , 1)}m(y) \mathrm{d} y,
$$
with $\alpha$ and $\varepsilon$ positive constants.

Assuming $\int_{-1}^{1} m(x) \mathrm{d} x = 1$ I should be able to solve for $\lambda$, which is the quantity I'm actually interested in.

So far I've only been able to solve for the trivial case where $\varepsilon > 1 + \alpha$, for which I obtain $\lambda = 1/\varepsilon$. Also, for $\alpha > 1$ and $\varepsilon < \alpha - 1$ I can get $\lambda = 1/\alpha$, while for $\alpha \leq 1$ and $\varepsilon < 1 - \alpha$, I have that $\lambda = 1$.

All other cases:

1. $\alpha > 1$, $\varepsilon \in (\alpha - 1, \alpha + 1)$
2. $\alpha < 1$, $\varepsilon \in ( 1 - \alpha, \alpha + 1)$

I can't find a solution to.

Do you know if there a "relatively easy" way to compute such integrals or a reference that could point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: $\lambda$ can be interpreted as an eigenvalue of a certain integral operator. Have you explored this way ?

Comment: The origin of the problem is indeed an eigenfunctional equation. In this setting (cases 1,2) it ensures that $\lambda \in (0,1)$ but I can't get anything else from it.

Comment: I think it would be good that you give more context : what has brought you to be interested by this expression ? A personal intuition : isn't it amenable to a [box-spline](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michele.vergne/pageperso/transparents_conferences/pisalecture1.pdf) issue ?

Comment: Can you assume $m$ an even function ?

Comment: Yes, $m$ is an even function, I should have mentioned that. The question arises from computing [quasi-stationary distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-stationary_distribution#:~:text=In%20probability%20a%20quasi%2Dstationary,long%20time%20without%20reaching%20it.) in the theory of conditioned random dynamics. I'll look carefully at the box-spline problem, thanks!